# UiPath Select Activity - Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: drop-down-menu, uipath, peoplesoft, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

I am using UiPath Studio 2022.4.5 on an Azure instance when using a Select activity to select a drop down value on a Peoplesoft application page in Chrome browser. I am using the modern experience. I have checked the Chrome browser version and its the latest updated version.

I get this error intermittently but frequently on the same drop down element on different transactions. I have a delay of 2 before the select activity is executed.

Any insight would be much appreciated on this.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using Wait for page load property on the Select item:
[image]